# Is it possible to create an interactive grid in Arduino to send positional DMX data to an intelligent light fixture?

Tags: arduino

I am creating a project at uni, which I hope to create an interactive grid, overlaid on a video stream, to send positional data to an intelligent lighting fixture.  I am hoping to use Arduino for this project, however I am struggling to find any articles on this saying its possible.  I am going to use feedback from potentiometers attached to the pivot points of the light to provide the boundaries to work within. I will be using a dmx shield to send data back to the light.  The only solution that I have been able to come up with is to create a series of buttons with the subsequent equations attached to the button.  This, however, is not practical.  Is there an easier way to achieve this goal. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a bunch of different questions - which part is the issue? Arduino is not normally used for video, you don't say whether the buttons are physical or UI elements, so there are too many parts missing to answer.

Comment: The creation of the grid user interface is the main issue.  The buttons were going to be UI buttons representing each point on the grid.